# How is memory allocated in c , and why diffrence between two contiguous is always 4?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    int *x;
    x = malloc(sizeof(long long)*3);
    scanf("%i %i %i",x, (x+1), (x+2));
    printf("%i\t %i\t %i\n",(int)x, (int)(x+1), (int)(x+2));
    printf("%i\t %i\t %i\n",*x, *(x+1), *(x+2));
    free(x);
}
```

The output of this program for input 12,2,3 is :

```
43171856         43171860        43171864
12       2       3
```

so, my question is why difference between address is 4 in each case , 
and if `*x` points to `43171856` then `*(x+1)` should point to `4317185` not `43171860`? `sizeof(long long)` is also `8` bytes , so how allocated memory allocates `8` bytes between those `4` bytes between `43171856` and `43171860`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the really confusing bits of C: `x+1`, when `x` has a pointer type, increments the numeric value of `x` by `sizeof(*x)`, *not* by 1.

It has to be that way, because, for any pointer type `T *x`, `x+1` is the same as `&x[1]`. `&x[1]` is the address of the second `T` in the pseudo-array pointed to by `x`.  Therefore the numeric value of `x+1` must be equal to the numeric value of `x` plus `sizeof(T)`, which in your case is 4.

`malloc`, meanwhile, doesn't know that you passed it `3*sizeof(long long)`.  It sees `malloc(24)` and it gives you 24 bytes, which (on your platform) is *six* `int`s.  You are using only the first three, which is fine, it just wastes a little memory.  You probably meant to write `3*sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in your code

```
 printf("%i\t %i\t %i\n",(int)x, (int)(x+1), (int)(x+2));
```

invokes implementation defined behaviour, as you're trying to cast a pointer to integer.

If you want to print pointers

- use `%p` format specifier
- cast the argument to `void *`.

---

That said, pointer arithmetic honors the data type. You had declared `x` to be a pointer to `int`, so any pointer arithmetic will be based on `sizeof(int)`, whatever that evaluates to in your platform.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6/P8, (*emphasis mine*)

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
>   result has the type of the pointer operand. **If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression**. In other words, if the expression `P` points to
>   the `i`-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and
>   `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist. [....]

In your code, you wrote

```
 x = malloc(sizeof(long long)*3);
```

which is *erroneous*. In *this* case, you may be on the safer side, as `sizeof(long long)` is `>=` `sizeof(int)`, but that is not true for any arbitary type.

- Best case: You'll end up wasting memory.
- Worst case: You'll end up accessing out of bound (invalid) memory.

A better and preferred way to write this would be

```
 x = malloc(sizeof*x * 3);   //sizeof is not a function :)
```

and then, check for `malloc()` success. This allocates the exact amount of memory required, no more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an int* which usually is 32 bits and thus 4 bytes.
Try using a long long *x instead? 
You have as you stated allocated 8*3 bytes byt are only using 4*3 bytes of them..
Each offeset i.e (x+1) is only offseted the size of an int.

Answer (score 0):

[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the **`sizeof`** operator, <strike>the **`_Alignof`** operator</strike>, or the
> unary **`&`** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

AFAIK, the `_Alignof` operator clause is a mistake in the online draft that was corrected in the official™, not freely-available standard, which is why it's struck out in the quote above.

> **6.5.2 Array subscripting**
> ...
> 2    A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
> designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator **`[]`**
> is that **`E1[E2]`** is identical to **`(*((E1)+(E2)))`**. Because of the conversion rules that
> apply to the binary **`+`** operator, if **`E1`** is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
> initial element of an array object) and **`E2`** is an integer, **`E1[E2]`** designates the **`E2`**-th
> element of **`E1`** (counting from zero).

Given an array `a` of type `T` and an integer `i`, the expression `a[i]` is equivalent to (defined as) `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`, offset `i` *elements* of type `T` (**not bytes**) from that address and dereference the result.

If `a` is an array or pointer expression and `i` is an integral expression, then `a[i]` and `i[a]` will yield the same result.

> **6.5.6 Additive Operators**
> ...
> 8    When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression **`P`** points to
> the *i*-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and
> `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value *n*) point to, respectively, the *i*+*n*-th and *i*−*n*-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression `P` points to the last
> element of an array object, the expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression `Q` points one past the last element of an array object, the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary **`*`** operator that is evaluated.

If `p` is a pointer to an object of type `T`, then the expression `p + 1` yields the address of the *next object* of that type.  If `sizeof (T)` is 1, then `p + 1` adds 1 to the address.  If `sizeof (T)` is 4, then `p + 1` adds *4* to the address.

Similarly, the expression `++p` and `p++` advance `p` to point to the next *object* of type `T`.